# Does javadoc comments gets eliminated/removed during Lexical Analysis phase in Compilation process? Is it included in your final .class file?

Tags: java

javadoc comments are included in .class file or not?

Answer (score 2):

```
/* text */
```

The compiler ignores everything from `/*` to `*/`.

More information:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/writingdoccomments-137785.html